# Extract text from url using Nginx

Tags: nginx

I am trying to find a way to extract some text from a url to be used in alias. 
The url is something like:

```
/test/user_code_name/
```

and the alias should be

```
/test1/user_name/
```

So the idea is to just remove the part between _ and _ and use it like a variable.

Thx
L.

Answer (score 2):

try these settings:

```
location / {
   if ( $request_uri ~ ^/(.*)/(.*)_.*_(.*)/$ ) {
       rewrite ^ /$1/$2_$3/ break;
   }
}
```

Please read more about nginx rewrite module [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html)